# Eclipse treats "src" folder as a package after using git

Tags: eclipse, git

After doing a `git pull` to my pc, eclipse treats the `src` folder as part of the package name, so all of my classes give me an error on the package line.

Answer (score 1):

The archive .classpath was conflicting, that's why it was bugging